# insert value in a column by checking multiple values in another column

Tags: sql, case

i have a table as follows:

[image]

as u can see my level 4 column is empty so i need sql query to get "no" if any of the particular style (1401,1201) has dead as "0".
level 1 was group by style and name both whereas level 4 is group by only style.
i got answer for level 1 but struggling with level 4 
i tried somewhat similar approach for level 4 also as level 1 but didnt get any desired answer

my desired answer is that for 1201 all the values in level 4 should be yes whereas for 1401 it should be no
thank you.

Comment: please format ur question, we cant see your level 4 column, if its empty or not

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i am using sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

You can find the min value of `dead` for each style. Assuming your table is named `test`:

```
with cte as
(
select style, min(cast(dead as int)) as dead
from test
group by style
)
update test
set level4 = case when cte.dead = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end
from test inner join cte on cte.style = test.style
```

I'm assuming your `dead` flag is bit, that's why the cast to int is needed.

Comment: i am getting answer it would be great if u can explain me "With cte" stuff

Comment: it's [common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). does it answer your question?

Comment: yeah got the idea of cte thanx.